# sum of rounded values of three integers

Tags: java

Write a program that reads 3 integers and prints their sum of their rounded values.. We'll round each value up to the next multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is 5 or more, so 15 rounds up to 20. Alternately, round down to the previous multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is less than 5, so 12 rounds down to 10.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    int z = scan.nextInt();
    int a = x%10;
    int b = y%10;
    int c = z%10;
    int sum = 0;

    if(a >= 5)
        a = 10;
    else
        a = 0;

    if(b >= 5)
        b = 10;
    else
        b = 0;

    if(c >= 5)
        c = 10;
    else
        c = 0;

    sum = x+y+z;

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

I know it's wrong but I don't know how to correct it. Please help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not getting the correct output so there must be something wrong with the code, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The next multiple of 10, isn't always the number 10. And you never rounded `x`, `y` or `z`.

Comment: What does your code do? Why did you write it this way?

Comment: Please, write some program for me?

Comment: I rounded the last digits of x, y and z.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to round `x`, `y` and `z` to the multiple of `10`. You have the modulus in `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. If the modulus is less than `5`, you can just subtract it. If the modulus is greater than or equal to `5` you want to add the difference of the modulus and ten to the original number. So you need something like (for `x`, `y` and `z`),

```
if (a >= 5) {
    x += 10 - a;
} else {
    x -= a;
}
```

Which you could express as a ternary like

```
x += (a >= 5) ? 10 - a : -a;
y += (b >= 5) ? 10 - b : -b;
z += (c >= 5) ? 10 - c : -c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`, shouldn't you be modifying `x`, `y`, `z`?  Example:

```
    if(a >= 5)
        x = (x/10 +1) * 10;
    else
        x = (x/10) * 10;
```

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Change two lines:

```
int sum =  x - a + y - b + z - c;
```

and

```
sum += a + b + c;
```

The first reduces x, y, z by the integer digit. The second adds the values resulting from rounding the integer digit to 0 or 10.